# R simmer simple mine simulation

Tags: r

I would like to set up a simulation of a mining operation using R simmer but I've not been able to get very far.  As a simple example, I would like to set up a simulation of trucks being loaded underground by a bogger, then the trucks traveling up a decline to the run-of-mine (RoM) pad to dump their load, then returning to the bogger again (vai the decline) to be loaded again. The objective is to find the best number of trucks to do this job without the bogger having to wait too long for a truck to load and not having the trucks queue up too long at the bogger or the RoM.  I'm attempting to follow the simmer tutorial found [here](https://r-simmer.org/articles/simmer-01-introduction.html).

So first I need to set up a trajectory for the truck, which I've set up as follows:

```
# Load DES simulation package and set random seed
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
require(simmer)
set.seed(1234)

# Set up trajectory for a truck being loaded by a bogger to Rom and back again
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Truck <- trajectory('Truck path') %>%
  # loaded by bogger
  seize('Bogger',1) %>%
  timeout(function() rnorm(1, 3, 0.5)) %>%
  release('Bogger',1) %>%
  # go up decline
  seize('Decline',1) %>%
  timeout(function() rnorm(1, 6, 1)) %>%
  release('Decline',1) %>%
  # dump on ROM
  seize('RoM',1) %>%
  timeout(function() rnorm(1,2,0.5)) %>%
  release('RoM', 1) %>%
  # go down decline 
  seize('Decline',1) %>%
  timeout(function() rnorm(1, 6, 1)) %>%
  release('Decline',1)
```

Now my first question is then how does this account for the fact that the truck travels follow a continuous loop? as in ... bogger -> up decline -> RoM -> down decline -> bogger.  Should the trajectory be specified this looping path?

Next, I set up a simulation environment as follows:

```
# Set up simulation enviroment
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
env %>%
    add_resource('Bogger',1) %>%
    add_resource('Decline',1) %>%
    add_resource('RoM', 1) %>%
    add_generator('Truck', Truck, function() rnorm(1, 6, 1))
```

When executed I end up with the following error message (at which point I'm stuck)

```
Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'env' not found
```

I'm also confused as to why I need to add a function for the times for the truck arrivals when this is already specified in the trajectory chain?

Apologies for the likely very dumb questions but am tapping around in the dark on this type of modeling for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your model by taking out the decline resource since I am assuming that multiple trucks can be going up/down at the same time and what you want is to see what the queue time is at Bogger and RoM.  To handle the continuous loop, I initially create the number of trucks required at time zero, and then as each one completes, you can use the 'activate' to start up the truck again.  It was put in function so you can see the results of varying the number of the trucks.

```
library(simmer)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)


# create a function so we can call it with varying number of trucks
f_mine_simulation <- function(n_trucks)
{
  env <- simmer("SuperDuperSim")  # define environment

  # Set up trajectory for a truck being loaded by a bogger to Rom and back again
  # I am assuming that multiple trucks can use the ramp, so it is not setup
  # as a resource.  
  #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Truck <- trajectory('Truck path') %>%
    # loaded by bogger
    seize('Bogger',1) %>%
    timeout(function() rnorm(1, 3, 0.5)) %>%
    release('Bogger',1) %>%
    # go up decline
    timeout(function() rnorm(1, 6, 1)) %>%
    # dump on ROM
    seize('RoM',1) %>%
    timeout(function() rnorm(1,2,0.5)) %>%
    release('RoM', 1) %>%
    # go down decline 
    timeout(function() rnorm(1, 6, 1)) %>%
    activate("Truck_gen")

    # Set up simulation enviroment
    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    env %>%
    add_resource('Bogger',1) %>%
    add_resource('Decline',1) %>%
    add_resource('RoM', 1) %>%
    add_generator('Init', Truck, at(rep(0,n_trucks))) %>%
    add_generator("Truck_gen", Truck, when_activated()) %>%
    run(10000) 

    # calculate the amount of waiting at the Bogger and RoM 
    return(get_mon_resources(env) %>%
        group_by(resource) %>%
        summarise(active = sum(head(server, -1) * diff(time)),
                  waiting = sum(head(queue, -1) * diff(time)),
                  n_trucks = n_trucks
        ))
}

# run for 1-10 trucks
x <- map_dfr(1:10, f_mine_simulation)
```

When it was run, here was the results:

```
> x
# A tibble: 20 x 4
   resource active waiting n_trucks
   <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <int>
 1 Bogger    1758.     0          1
 2 RoM       1173.     0          1
 3 Bogger    3461.   148.         2
 4 RoM       2347.    55.0        2
 5 Bogger    5199.   542.         3
 6 RoM       3414.   124.         3
 7 Bogger    6757.  1326.         4
 8 RoM       4502.   273.         4
 9 Bogger    8326.  2688.         5
10 RoM       5471.   559.         5
11 Bogger    9485.  5732.         6
12 RoM       6253.   756.         6
13 Bogger    9965. 12660.         7
14 RoM       6650.   942.         7
15 Bogger    9999. 22415.         8
16 RoM       6622.   966.         8
17 Bogger    9999. 32383.         9
18 RoM       6690.   956.         9
19 Bogger   10000. 42647.        10
20 RoM       6585.   968.        10
```

So you will have to decide what is the best number based on the queue size (waiting time) that you want.  You can see that for 10,000 time units of simulation, there was a 42,647 total wait time for for the simulation with 10 trucks.  You can see that the Bogger becomes saturated (using 8326 seconds of time -- 83% busy) at around 5 trucks.  There was only a total wait time of 968 at RoM since it has a shorter service time.

You can see how fast the "wait time" is going up after about 5 trucks (almost 10000 seconds increments) since the Bogger is saturated and everyone is just waiting.

Comment: The `rollback` activity would be appropriate here too. See section 4.3 "Best practices" in the [JSS paper](https://r-simmer.org/articles/simmer-02-jss.pdf).